# Mongoose referenced field missing after making a new schema object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB with NodeJS using mongoose package, trying to save an object to DB, one of the fields is missing... checked everything.

the problem: I don't know why it's happening, I have every field as it suppose to be saved to the DB according to the question schema. For some how, when i generate a new question schema object and apply the requested details to it, every field apply except the referenced one, (the topic ) to the new question schema. am I missing something here, I checked before the new question object all the field are good including the referenced one - shows the correct id's of the topics.

I have this topic schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Question = require("./Question.js");

var topic_schema = Schema({  
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    questions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Topic', topic_schema);
```

And i have this question schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Topic = require("./Topic.js");

var question_schema = Schema({
    syntax: {type: String, required: true},
    answer: {type: String, required: true},
    topic: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Topic' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', question_schema);
```

I'm trying to save a question in this route:

```
app.post('/addque', function (req,res){
  // Getting the details from the client request
  var question_details = req.body.question_details;

  // Getting the id's of the topics
  Topic.find({name: {"$in": question_details.topics}}).select('_id').exec(function (err, topics){
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    // Apply the id's to the question_details
    question_details.topics = topics;

    // ~~~~~~~~~~Generate new questions object~~~~~~~~~ topic array does not apply here
    var question_to_save = question_details;

    //Save it to the DB
    question_details.save(function(err, saved_question) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
  });
});
```

thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`topic` in the `question_schema` looks like it should be plural, `topics`.

I can't see `question_to_save` being used anywhere either.

Comment: can't believe i made this typo mistake in the schema 'topic' should have been topics.. as for question_to_save it seems i copied the last version in my code that did not had the part where i make the the new object schema.. thank you for noticed!

Comment: No worries, happy to help. :)